# can't access grub

Tags: grub2

I'm a beginer and installed ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7 but grub doesn't come up, it goes straight to windows.
I booted the live cd, in terminal typed `sudo fdisk -l` and this is what I got

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8de9b533

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 7747 MB, 7747397632 bytes
32 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7505 cylinders, total 15131636 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0a2a74d7
```

What can I do?

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63    15130079     7565008+   b  W95 FAT32
```

Comment: Well, like the output of `fdisk` says, you shouldn't use that because you are using a GPT-style partition table. This means you are probably using a UEFI (not BIOS) machine to boot from. Please include the output of the following commands instead: `sudo efibootmgr`, `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I did it but says sudo: efibootmgr: command not found

Comment: @Ron again, if you edit posts please fix all errors not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to fix this problem using the `boot-repair` utility. Boot your live CD in EFI mode, open a terminal, and enter these three commands, in order:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Then, launch Boot Repair from the Unity Dash and it will fix your problem (hopefully).